# Visual Studio Expand Method and All Child Scopes or Collapse Method Only?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have recently begun using <kbd>ctrl-m, o</kbd> to collapse the file to definitions in large files. However I do not like that this also collapses other child scopes of the method e.g. if {}, for{} blocks etc.

What I would like is one of two possible solutions:

1. Collapsing **only** collapses the method signatures, and leaves child blocks of the methods untouched (so that as soon as you expand the method, everything within it is expanded).
2. After collapsing everything with <kbd>ctrl-m, o</kbd> expanding a single method (not the whole file) should expand all child scopes as well.

Does anyone know if this is possible with the current shortcuts or know of any plugins that will help? **Note:** I mainly work in javascript files in case that makes any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can collapse sections by highlighting them and using <kbd>ctrl m, h</kbd>

Or to toggle whether the selection is open or closed, you can use <kbd>ctrl m, m</kbd>

To expand everything within the function, you need to select (highlight) the function rather than just having the cursor on that line before you press <kbd>ctrl m, m</kbd>

Comment: <kbd>ctrl m, m</kbd> is what I use to expand individual methods. But after using <kbd>ctrl m, o</kbd> to collapse to definition, it doesn't expand the for {} and if{} blocks within that function, which means I then have to manually use  <kbd>ctrl m, m</kbd> to expand all of those as well. I'm looking for a way to do them all on one shortcut.

Comment: `m,m` works for me - it expands the selected (highlighted) method and all it's children fully (in a js file) - I am using vs2015

Comment: Not for me unfortunately - i get stuff like this on using ctrl m, m to expand the function at the cursor:  http://postimg.org/image/lm5cp65sh/ . Are you running any plugins?

Comment: No native 2015 and tried in 2013 and it also works.  Are you highlighting the code you want to unexpand? if you just have the cursor on the line then it only expands the outer function, if you highlight the line then it should expand everything

Comment: Yes - that makes a difference and is something I can create a macro for. Thank you!